# Differences between ECIES and DHIES

Tags: encryption, public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, ecies

I'm studying the Integrated Encryption Scheme and I did't understand which are the main differences between ECIES and DHIES. Can someone help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for differences beyond the group being used?

Comment: Yes, because a part from the group used I didn't found any differences in the scheme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECIES is DHIES restricted to an Elliptic Curve group, when DHIES is defined for any cyclic group, including but not limited to $\Bbb Z_p^*$.

Mihir Bellare writes on his [web page on *DHIES: An encryption scheme based on the Diffie-Hellman Problem*](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/dhies.html) that it

> describes a Diffie-Hellman based encryption scheme, DHIES, (formerly named DHES and DHAES)..
>   The SEC1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography, v1.0 standard by SECG includes DHIES

and [SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography Ver. 1.0](http://www.secg.org/SEC1-Ver-1.0.pdf#page=75) (dated September 20, 2000) mentions ECIES stating that "It was proposed" in that article, referenced under the old name DHAES. [SEC 1 Ver. 2.0](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=95) references that article under the new name DHIES. Both versions of SEC1 are elliptic about the origin of the name ECIES.

---

Update: I read in Victor Shoup's [*A Proposal for an ISO Standard for Public Key Encryption*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2001/112.pdf#page=11) (version 2.1 dated December 20, 2001) that there was ECIES as proposed in P1363a (as drafted July 21, 2001), and ECIES-KEM, with only the later secure against adaptive chosen ciphertext attack (thru some compatible restriction).

The P1363a rationale (as drafted July 16, 2003 shortly before adoption) clarifies:

> <sup>**C.3.5 For the DL and EC families, why was the DL/ECIES encryption scheme selected?**</sup>
>   <sup>Several proposals on DL and EC encryption schemes were presented to the P1363 working group during the development of IEEE Std 1363-2000. None of the proposals was considered mature enough to include in IEEE Std 1363-2000 and it was expected that a suitable encryption scheme would be established during the P1363a effort. The DL/ECIES scheme has emerged as a common reference in several other standards efforts, including ANSI X9.63 [B12] and SEC-1 [SEC-1], with accompanying security analysis, and is thus considered appropriate for the amendment. DL/ECIES has two modes: non-DHAES mode, which is compatible with ANSI X9.63 and SEC-1 but does not have the full set of security properties of the DHAES scheme on which it is based (see Abdalla, Bellare, and Rogaway [ABR98]); and DHAES mode, which has the full set. (..)</sup>

In the end my reading is that draft DH(A)ES is history, DHIES never had issues, and ECIES is its restriction to an Elliptic Curve group.